# How to remove width is undefined error in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am getting an error of width of undefined in jQuery. I'm trying to implement a [jQuery Vector Map](http://jqvmap.com/).

Using the USA example, here is  my code:

```
<script src="js/jquery.vmap.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.vmap.usa.js"></script>
 
<script>
jQuery('#vmap').vectorMap({
    map: 'usa_en',
    backgroundColor: null,
    color: '#ffffff',
    hoverColor: '#999999',
    selectedColor: '#666666',
    enableZoom: true,
    showTooltip: true,
    selectedRegions: ['MO', 'FL', 'OR']
});
</script>
 
<div id="vmap" style="width: 600px; height: 400px;"></div>
```

Here is the demo:
[plnkr.co/edit/Znj282gvC0AdPMun14Az](http://plnkr.co/edit/Znj282gvC0AdPMun14Az?p=preview)

Comment: You're including Europe (`jquery.vmap.europe.js`) but you then define USA (`map: 'usa_en'`) as the map to use

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is a typo:

```
jquery.vmap.europe.js?dl=0 // you have this vmap "europe"
```

and you have referenced:

```
map: 'usa_en', // "usa"
```

---

[change it to:](http://plnkr.co/edit/sYTVmuAUThQBsdxOYRug?p=preview)

```
map: 'europe_en',
```